# Is there a pure peer to peer screen sharing app?

Tags: screen-sharing, peer-to-peer

I run a meetup, and we would like to share the presenter's screen for the people in the back.  However, wireless in the room doesn't always cooperate, and internet may not be available.  Is there a pure peer-to-peer screen sharing application that could be run 1-to-N over an ad-hoc network?

Comment: VNC? Have the presenter run the server, and the client connect to it? Won't work very well for video, but fr a presentation it should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VNC server and client should do the job. I like [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/), but there are many other implementations if you don't like this one for some reason.

You can setup the server to accept view-only connections without password, but remote control connections only with a password.

Comment: Looks good, though I won't get a chance to try it until next week.

Answer (score 1):

Also, try TightProjector, http://www.tightvnc.com/projector/ which "is a program that can transmit the screen of a particular Windows computer to other computers in the same local-area network. The data is transmitted continuously, in real time".

As far as VNC is concerned, I sometimes had problems with the (low frequency of) screen updates, at least with the old versions I tried in the past.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that, but there are a lot of non-windows machines in this group (my fault for not mentioning it)